# .htaccess page url getting problems

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I created two pages for accessing posts in my website these two pages links information displayed in header separately. In the header(bussiness..) link coming from section_category.php page and cities coming from city.php. Here i write htaccess code for section_category.php to display page url like this

```
http://campaignforindia.com/section_category.php?id=4
http://campaignforindia.com/4
```

I works good but city.php is not working

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) category.php?menu_id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ city_category.php?city_id=$1&city_name=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ post.php?nurl=$1 [NC]
```

I want to display second link like this

```
http://campaignforindia.com/city_category?city_id=15&city_name=Delhi
http://campaignforindia.com/15/delhi
```

**header.php**
This page is used to navigate two category pages(city.php,section_category.php)

```
<ul class="the-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <?php while($mrow = mysql_fetch_array($qry1)){  ?>
                        <?php  //$mname = strtolower($mrow['menu_name']); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $mrow['menu_id']; ?>"><?php echo $mrow['menu_name']; ?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>

                                                </ul>
```

```
                <!-- BEGIN .wrapper -->
                <div class="wrapper">

                    <ul>
                    <?php
                    while($crow = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                    {

                    ?>

                    <li><a href="city_category?city_id=<?php echo $crow['city_id']; ?>&city_name=<?php echo $crow['city_name']; ?>"><?php echo $crow['city_name']; ?></a></li> 

                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>

                <!-- END .wrapper -->
                </div>
```

Comment: sorry it is city_category.php page

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression of your first rule matches all cases.
Solutions for this:

- Switch the order of the two rules, or
- Write a stricter rule for the first match (e.g. `^([0-9]+)$` )